# What's the difference between "git log --diff-filter=R" and "git log --find-renames"?

Tags: git

I've learned in a video tutorial about the git command

`git log --diff-filter=R --find-renames`,

and by reading the docs I came to the conclusion that

`git log --diff-filter=R`

should yield the same results as

`git log --find-renames`

and the first combined command could be considered a typo.

Yet when I tried it in one repo, both commands separately yielded the same results, while in another repo only the latter one yielded any results.
Also, I can not find any documentation regarding possible differences between the two.

Can someone please tell me what the difference between these commands is besides the fact that you can add different modifiers to each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is really pretty simple:

- The `--find-renames` option turns on the rename-finding machinery, using the default 50%-similar file-matching threshold.  The rename-finding machinery is off by default in rather old versions of Git, and on by default in newer versions of Git, so if you have a newer version of Git (and have not changed the defaults), adding `--find-renames` to your `git diff` has no effect at all.<sup>1</sup>
- The `--diff-filter=` option sets up filters telling Git which files to selectively *display* after running the internal diff engine.  Selecting `R` tells Git to display *only* those files for which a rename was detected.

Hence, if you have an ancient version of Git, you need *both* options (or see footnote 1) to see only renamed files, but with a modern Git, just the `--diff-filter=R` option suffices unless the configuration for that repository has rename detection disabled.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are also several configuration knobs that you can set with `git config` or with `-c` options.  The most relevant here is `diff.renames`, which can be set to `false`, `true`, or either `copy` or `copies`.  See [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corewhitespace) for further details.  The default value of `diff.rename` changed from `false` to `true` in Git 2.9.0.